# R plots: customize point attributes

Tags: r, plot, attributes, point

I can easily specify the data point shape (pch) by adding a column to my data.  I am trying to understand why this does not also work for outline color (col) or fill (bg).  Note that the shapes do have attributes col and bg. Below is a subset of my data and the code, which works for pch, but not for col or bg.  Thanks!

```
X   Y   Shape   Line    Fill
104 87.238  22  "blue"  "pink"
693 255.985 21  "gold"  "gold"
15  33.069  24  "red"   "white"
414 289.072 24  "red"   grey
plot(data[,1:2],log="xy",pch=data[,3],col=data[,4],bg=data[,5])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
plot(data[,1:2],log="xy",pch=data[,3],
    col=as.character(data[,4]),bg=as.character(data[,5]))
```

Line and Fill were being treated as factors and therefore integers, not the strings that you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation!